# Use zip command to place in directory after zipping

Tags: command-line, backup, zip

I'm creating my backup script and have this:

```
DATE=$(date +"%m-%d-%Y")
zip -r backup.$DATE /home/folder/folder
```

First creates the date variable for the name, and the /home/folder/folder, I guess, is the directory to backup with all other directories and files associated. I need to make it so that it will place the zip in /mnt/backups when finished.

All help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @John1024 Do I need to do .zip like so  "/mnt/backups/backup.$DATE.zip"?

Comment: I would recommend always including the correct suffix (`.zip` in this case).  It is not "needed" but it is best practices.   So, yes, include it.  I would also recommend re-formating the date so that it sorts properly: `DATE=$(date +"%F")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To put the zip file in the correct directory:

```
Date=$(date +"%m-%d-%Y")
zip -r "/mnt/backups/backup.$Date" /home/folder/folder
```

One should avoid using all caps for shell variables.  The important system variables are all capitals and you don't want to accidentally overwrite one of them.  Thus, the above uses the mixed-case `Date` instead of `DATE`.

I would, as you suggested, `.zip` as the suffix.  This avoids possible confusion in the future.  Also, there is no need here to create a `Date` variable at all:

```
zip -r "/mnt/backups/backup.$(date +"%m-%d-%Y").zip" /home/folder/folder
```

Finally, dates in the month-day-year format do not sort properly.  The yyyy-mm-dd format will sort naturally in the right order.  The abbreviation for this common format is `%F`.  So:

```
zip -r "/mnt/backups/backup.$(date +"%F").zip" /home/folder/folder
```